# How can I call a class in another class

Tags: java, class, input, output

lets say I have a Main class which my main program runs with it.

```
public calss Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.print("input Length ");
       a = in.nextInt();
       System.out.print("input Height ");
       b = in.nextInt();
       ...
       (The code that goes in between?)
       ...
       System.out.println("output");
   }
}
```

How can I use another class and input it in side my first class lets say if its a simple calculation class like

```
pubic class Math{
    output = a*b
}
```

and have like this input and output:

```
input Length 2
input Height 3
6
```

By the way don't vote down for me cause I'm noob! common why you do this? XD

Comment: Might be worthwhile going through these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Its simple as that.

```
public class Test{
  public int multiplication(int a, int b){
   return a*b;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.print("input Length ");
       a = in.nextInt();
       System.out.print("input Height ");
       b = in.nextInt();
       ...
       Test t = new Test();
       System.out.println(t.multiplication(a,b));
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes you want an instance of the class `Test` to work with - there's no need for that, as the multiplication is stateless. In this example, as it's inside the same class as the main method, I would recommend calling it as a static function.

Comment: An explanation on the solution would be great

Comment: Also, the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a class with a method there.

If you want to put your calculation method in a class

e.g.

```
public class MyCalc {
    public static int calculate(int a, int b) { 
         return a*b;
    }
}
```

Then you could call that function from with your main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     // something


     int result = MyCalc.calculate(1,2);
}
```

That's how you'd use static functions in a utility class to modularise some functionality. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Your second class may have fields and methods as well. For your example, your `Math` class should have a method were you perform the multiplication of two integers, and it should receive these integers as parameters. Here's a small example on it:

```
public class Math {
    //declaring the method as static
    //no need to create an instance of the class to use it
    //the method receives two integer arguments, a and b
    //the method returns the multiplication of these numbers
    public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

But be careful, do not name your class with the same name of built-in classes in Java, **specially classes in `java.lang` package. Yes, there is a built-in [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class in Java.

So, it would be better to rename your class to something like this:

```
public class IntegerOperations {
    public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

And you will use it like this (after fixing your current code):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Use a Scanner to read user input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("input Length ");
        //declare the variables properly
        int a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input Height ");
        int b = in.nextInt();

        //declare another variable to store the result
        //returned from the method called
        int output = Operations.multiply(a, b);

        System.out.println("output: " + output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh right I forgot about the Math class Thank you though very helpful!